# Getting status 400 as an error instead of json response

Tags: reactjs, json, rest, express, axios

I have a front-end connected to back-end, using http requests.
I'm experiencing this thing where if I return res.status(200) I get a response which I can send with that response a message. But when I'm sending res.status(400). I'm getting an red error on console rather than a parsable response.

```js
app.post('/new', (req, res) => {
    const { fullname, phone, country, img } = req.body
    return res.status(200).json({
        title: 'Ok, we got you!'
    })
})

// If I'm changing that status to 400 I get that red error on console and I cannot parse from it anything (anything atleast that I want)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and that's the correct behaviour with HTTP requests. [`HTTP 400 Bad Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) indicates an error rather then a successful response from your web server. So you need to catch the error thrown by the server with either a `.catch()` clause or a `try/catch` block in order to access the data returned on your client side. You're server code is absolutely fine. Just add the code below to your client side application.

###### Using `.catch` approach

```js
axios.get('/foo')
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.data.title); // your title
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
  });
```

###### Using `try/catch` approach

```js
try {
  const resp = await axios.get('/foo');
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data);
  console.log(error.response.data.title); // your title
  console.log(error.response.status);
  console.log(error.response.headers);
}
```

- For more information visit this [link](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)

Comment: thanks! you're amazing, thats for also linking me to the axios docs, should've read them earlier